# One player, but more buttons

Tags: android, video-streaming, android-videoview, exoplayer

So far we have created a player for each stream. But I said to learn to do it right.
How can I make more buttons that each has a streaming address to open in the same videoview.
I think there should be a way toString or getstring.
Specifically, m3u8 address to send to another activity, where Andres m3u8 be extracted and put into videoview.

videoview.xml

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener  {

protected EMVideoView emVideoView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    emVideoView = (EMVideoView)findViewById(R.id.video_play_activity_video_view);
    emVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(this);

    //For now we just picked an arbitrary item to play.  More can be found at
    //https://archive.org/details/more_animation
    emVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("http://xxxxxxxxxx/xxxx/xx.m3u8"));


    //-----------------------
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 11 && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19) { // lower api
        View v = this.getWindow().getDecorView();
        v.setSystemUiVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
        //for new api versions.
        View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
        int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY;
        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
    }


    //---------
}


@Override
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
    //Starts the video playback as soon as it is ready
    emVideoView.start();
}
```

}

what I want as a button to send "address streaming" to videoview.but I do not know how can I make a string to be sent from one activity to another.

```
emVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("here come the string of the button was pressed"));
```

This is not work

```
>  Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
>         String url = bundle.getString("url");
> 
>         emVideoView = (EMVideoView)findViewById(R.id.video_play_activity_video_view);
>         emVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(this);
> 
>         //For now we just picked an arbitrary item to play.  More can be found at
>         //https://archive.org/details/more_animation
>         emVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(getString(R.string.url)));
```

button:

```
>         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
>         Intent intent = new Intent(Main2Activity.this, MainActivity.class);
>         intent.putExtra("url", "http://xxxxx/xxx.m3u8");
>         startActivity(intent);
```

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the correct version is:
going very well.
But how can I get url and from other applications?

> Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
>           String url = bundle.getString("url");
>
> ```
>     emVideoView = (EMVideoView)findViewById(R.id.video_play_activity_video_view);
>     emVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(this);
>
>     //For now we just picked an arbitrary item to play.  More can be found at
>     //https://archive.org/details/more_animation
>     emVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(url)));
> ```